# sudoers doesn't work

Tags: sudo, powertop, visudo

I added powertop to /etc/sudoers (sudo visudo) but it doesn't work. I checked all possible problems I can imagine. What did I missed?

```
user@ellie:~$ whoami
user
user@ellie:~$ groups
user adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
user@ellie:~$ ll /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 1093 Feb  6 19:05 /etc/sudoers

user@ellie:~$ sudo powertop
[sudo] Passwort für user: 
user@ellie:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep powertop
[sudo] Passwort für user: 
ALL ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/powertop
user@ellie:~$ which powertop
/usr/sbin/powertop
user@ellie:~$ BB
```

I am in group sudo, permissions seem to be ok, path to powertop checked. But you see, if I type in "sudo powertop" it ask for a password ?!?
(In my first attempt the first "ALL" was just "user")

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I have to create a new file:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/mysudo
```

Putting my lines there helps. As a reason was stated the order of lines, last rule wins.

I accept this, but frankly speaking don't understand. In my sudoers is

```
# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

As you can see includdir is even commented out and I don't know what this lines interfere with my add on. So, if someone can explain that - I would like to understand this.

Comment: It seems you are asking a new question in your answer. Instead of doing that, [edit] your question or ask a new one.